# GTM vip creation with ansible and error is msg: 01070226: pool members test_auto_https references a nonexistence virtaul server

Tags: react-gtm-module

I am facing an error while automating GTM vip creation with ansible and error is msg: 01070226: pool members test_auto_https references a nonexistence virtaul server.

### @error at adding members to existing GTM pool

- name: adding existing vip to gtm pool
  bigip_gtm_pool_member:
  pool: gtm_pool
  type: a
  aggregate:
  - server_name: f5_box_name
  virtual_server: test_auto_https
  partition: Common
  member_order: 1
  state: present
  provider: ""{{ provider}}"
  delegate_to: localhost

I am facing an error while automating GTM vip creation with ansible and error is msg: 01070226: pool members test_auto_https references a nonexistence virtaul server.

@error at adding members to existing GTM pool
can you any one help on solving the above error in GTM vip creation process  by ansible modules